# akward ternary evaluation in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very confused about some ternary expression in ruby.

I have this expression:

```
puts respond_to? "greeting".to_sym ? "hello" : "bye"
```

of course, that isn't what i'm doing in my app, is just for you to see.

the thing is that the above expression returns

```
false
```

when it should be returning `hello` if the method exists and `bye` if it don't right?

if i change the expression to

```
puts respond_to?("greeting".to_sym) ? "hello" : "bye"
```

it returns the right thing, either "hello" if it exists and "bye" otherwise.

Why is this happening? Is there something about ternary expression in  ruby that i don't know?

Just for you to know the right code in my app is:

```
respond_to?(path.to_sym) ? self.send(path) : "#"
```

Which returns the right path for the db stored header menus and if it don't exists, it will simply put an "#" to avoid errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the parenthesis for respond_to, the evaluation happens like this

```
"greeting".to_sym ? "hello" : "bye" #results in "hello"

puts respond_to? "hello" #results in false
```

ternary expression will get evaluated first without the parenthesis for `respond_to`

Answer (score 5):

Without the parentheses, it seems your code is being interpreted like this:

```
puts respond_to?("greeting".to_sym ? "hello" : "bye")
```

The stuff in the parenthesis is then evaluating to "hello", and `self` apparently doesn't respond to that, so `respond_to?` returns `false`.

This is why it's always a good idea to use parentheses whenever there's any doubt about the order of operations of your code; it makes your code more readable and eliminates mistakes such as this one.

Answer (score 2):

I ran `ruby --dump parsetree` on your example (always a good way to see what's really happening). In the version without argument parenthesis, the ternary gets evaluated and `respond_to?` checks for `"hello"` or "bye". In the second case the code does what you intend.

Without parenthesis:

```
# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1)
# +- nd_tbl: (empty)
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_FCALL (line: 1)
#     +- nd_mid: :puts
#     +- nd_args:
#         @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1)
#         +- nd_alen: 1
#         +- nd_head:
#         |   @ NODE_FCALL (line: 1)
#         |   +- nd_mid: :respond_to?
#         |   +- nd_args:
#         |       @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1)
#         |       +- nd_alen: 1
#         |       +- nd_head:
#         |       |   @ NODE_IF (line: 1)
#         |       |   +- nd_cond:
#         |       |   |   @ NODE_CALL (line: 1)
#         |       |   |   +- nd_mid: :to_sym
#         |       |   |   +- nd_recv:
#         |       |   |   |   @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |       |   |   |   +- nd_lit: "greeting"
#         |       |   |   +- nd_args:
#         |       |   |       (null node)
#         |       |   +- nd_body:
#         |       |   |   @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |       |   |   +- nd_lit: "hello"
#         |       |   +- nd_else:
#         |       |       @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |       |       +- nd_lit: "bye"
#         |       +- nd_next:
#         |           (null node)
#         +- nd_next:
#             (null node)
```

With:

```
# @ NODE_SCOPE (line: 1)
# +- nd_tbl: (empty)
# +- nd_args:
# |   (null node)
# +- nd_body:
#     @ NODE_FCALL (line: 1)
#     +- nd_mid: :puts
#     +- nd_args:
#         @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1)
#         +- nd_alen: 1
#         +- nd_head:
#         |   @ NODE_IF (line: 1)
#         |   +- nd_cond:
#         |   |   @ NODE_FCALL (line: 1)
#         |   |   +- nd_mid: :respond_to?
#         |   |   +- nd_args:
#         |   |       @ NODE_ARRAY (line: 1)
#         |   |       +- nd_alen: 1
#         |   |       +- nd_head:
#         |   |       |   @ NODE_CALL (line: 1)
#         |   |       |   +- nd_mid: :to_sym
#         |   |       |   +- nd_recv:
#         |   |       |   |   @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |   |       |   |   +- nd_lit: "greeting"
#         |   |       |   +- nd_args:
#         |   |       |       (null node)
#         |   |       +- nd_next:
#         |   |           (null node)
#         |   +- nd_body:
#         |   |   @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |   |   +- nd_lit: "hello"
#         |   +- nd_else:
#         |       @ NODE_STR (line: 1)
#         |       +- nd_lit: "bye"
#         +- nd_next:
#             (null node)
```